# SSH on Raspberypi hang or frozen

Tags: raspbian, ssh, linux, terminal

I have direct connection with Raspberry pi via ethernet cable on linux machine. if i run `ssh pi@10.42.0.22` i could establish secure connection. the problem i encountered is raspberry hang or frozen anytime run `ifconfig eth0 0`or trying to bring bridge interface. similarly this problem persist with my other three (3)pi. have read much and no solution for this.

Comment: of course if you disable the ethernet port then the ethernet port wont be able to sustain an ssh connection - It's like if you wanted to change a light fitting, at night, with no torch or other means of lighting ... and complain that turning the light off at the main switch makes it dark

Comment: of course i agree with you. actually am running a mesh topology on raspberrys and all the interface interconnected to other raspberrypi i.e eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3, eth4 using usb ethernet adapter. the only way i can i start up an ovs is to ssh into pi eth0. although hang and frozen of the pi persist where Crt C dont even work. i tried sudo ifconfig br0 10.42.0.22  netmask 255.255.255.0 up. still frozen. is there any method available to start up all the interfaces without hanging

Comment: Do a script that runs all commands even when disconnecting. Include commands for bringing the interface back on-line when finished. Run script. Profit. OR use hdmi and a keyboard to attach the Pi to your TV, then type directly into the PI. Easier than the ethernet connection that you manually disconnect and can't re-establish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to achieve but you are connected to the RasPi with `ssh`. That needs a configured and running interface, in your case **eth0**. If you reconfigure **eth0** then the connection is broken and of course also your `ssh` connection.

There are several ways to don't cut the branch that carries you. Use a monitor on hdmi, use a TTL to USB adapter for the serial console, use a second interface only for ssh without touching its configuration, use a batch file that will bring back the interfaces, use systemd-networkd to activate configuration after reboot ...

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for adding alias interface is `ifconfig eth0:0` (with `:`). IP must be available and from the same subnet.